# Android - Notifications and lifecycles

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-lifecycle

I have my app to carry out a notification when a given condition occurs.

The target intent is the main class Activity of my App.

If I click on the notification in the drawer and my App is already running, a new instance of the class is created (I can tell it is a new class from the debugger for one thing).

When the newly created window appears it is showing as my App when I look at the tasks running, but is the only instance of that App.

1. What happened to the original instance of my Activity class, and what happened to the original instance of the App?
2. Can I be sure there is only one instance of the Activity running ?

Thanks

Comment: add the tag for your `Activity` in the manifest `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` - ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Thanks @MarkKeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The original instance should still be there, but in the backstack. You should be able to reach it via the back button. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

2) Mark Keen's answer is correct here -- use android:launchMode="singleInstance" for the  tag of your activity in your android manifest. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Thanks @karljamoralin

Comment: In my specific case I have an activity which is being triggered when a user selects a notification in the notification drawer.  This activity calls StartActivity on the Activity I am interested in keeping to a single instance.   The first activity passes information about the notification to  the second instance using intent.PutExtra().  However, my single instance can now no longer access this information via Intent.Extras.GetString(), when it wakes up in OnResume().  What is best practise for new instance of an Activity can pass data to a singleInstance of an Activity which is being woken up

Comment: You need to override `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` in your singleinstance activity. The extras will be in `intent`.